# Naming convention for property

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, coding-style

Which one is preferable or more clear?

```
public int FrozenRegionWidth { get; set; }
```

Or...

```
public int WidthOfFrozenRegion { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please add language tag, some people are not sure what language you are talking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say FrozenRegionWidth, otherwise you'll end up with a whole bunch of properties starting with 'WidthOf..'.

Having said that, shouldn't you have something like FrozenRegion.Width (another reason why I'd look for FrozenRegionWidth over WidthOfFrozenRegion)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd would prefer FrozenRegionWidth.

For more informations refer to .NET framework naming guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a question for this community.  I believe it must be a question for your team.

If I was only developer on a team and I have to choose a name, I would create a  FrozenRegion class with Width property.

Comment: I think it's question for this community. I don't think this is project specific. The question could have been written as WidthOfBlabla or BlablaWidth?

Answer (score 0):

FrozenRegionWidth is what is used everywhere. You just can't use

```
NameOfCustomer
```

instead of

```
CustomerName
```

This makes our variable short n sweet. You can't go on writing long sentences as variable names.
And here you're creating an autoproperty. Remember that. It's more like a variable.

Answer (score 0):

But, consider the following scenario:

You are trying to look for the frozen region's width, but let say that you're not sure that it's called frozen region. Maybesome people call frozen region, another call it RegionThatIsFrozen (I know, lame example) or what ever: in that case, wouldn't it be easier for the programmer to type WidthOf and waits for the autocomplete to kicks in and choose the right one?

Comment: If you are talking about using Intellisense, is it realistic to expect all of the following conditions to be true:

 - Developers using your class are completely ignorant of it
 - The developers do not have any documentation to refer to
 - The class has so many properties that it is difficult to figure out which is which simply by skimming the Intellisense list
 - None of the properties have XML comments to describe what they are

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would prefere

```
public int FrozenRegionWidth { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would favour whichever form proffers the more generic information first in the name.

That is to say, I want it so that when I'm looking at a the member list in intellisense they're grouped according to how I want to find them. If "FrozenRegion" is what's important to me than I want to name the related properties FrozenRegionWidth, FrozenRegionFoo, FrozenRegionBar. If I'm looking at "Width" I want WidthFrozenRegion, WidthFoo, WidthBar.

So it depends on your usage, but name from most generic to most specific.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412839/naming-conventions-guidelines-for-verbs-nouns-and-english-grammar-usage) I asked on a similar vein may or may not help, it has indicators about noun choice.

To keep inline with the .NET BCL naming conventions I would use FrozenRegionWidth. It's unusual to include prepositions.

As mentioned above, FrozenWidth looks like a prime candidate for a struct/value type.